# Allow only find and insert action to mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb

I want to create collection. that allow only `insert` and `find` operation.
i read `Privilege Actions` in mongodb and i applied that method but all actions are performed like `remove` and `update`

i tried following

```
db.createRole({
  role: "master",
  privileges: [
    { resource: { db : "db_name",collection:"lock" }, actions: ["find","insert"] },
  ],
  roles : []
})



 db.grantPrivilegesToRole("master",[{resource : {db : "db_name",collection:"lock"},actions : ["find","insert"]}],{w : "majority"})
```

how to allow only `insert` and `find` ?

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**

Comment: Hi Kaushik; can I ask you to include some more information in your question? You've pasted in the code where you've created a role, but you really need to also show the follow-up steps: assigning that role to a user, connecting as that user, attempting an action such as _remove_ , and what mongodb does when you try that.

Comment: Hello Vince Bowdren, i am new in mongodb and i tried only above steps. i using mogodb 3.4 please can you help to solve this ?